# Clickable links with PagerAdapter

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter, android-pageradapter

I have some text displayed with FragmentPagerAdapter.
This text contains some links which I need to have clickable.
There is a solution using OnTouchEvent with a View, but how do I get the coordinates then?
Or is there a better solution for PagerAdapter?

EDIT: the code is:

```
private void setupPager() {
    if (pagerAdapter == null) {
        pagerAdapter = new TextFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pager.setCurrentItem(current_page);
    pager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private class TextFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public TextFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        spannable_page = null;
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        new PageForm(position, line_array, spannable_main).start();
        while (true) {
            if (spannable_page != null) {
                fragment = PageFragment.newInstance(spannable_page.get());
                break;
            }
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return total_pages;
    }
}
```

Inner class PageForm builds each page like this:

```
...
  Object[] spans_test = spannable.getSpans(start_range, end_range - 1, Object.class);
            CharSequence sequence_test = spannable.subSequence(start_range, end_range);
            SpannableStringBuilder builder_test = new SpannableStringBuilder();
            builder_test.insert(0, sequence_test);
            int sp_start, sp_end, flags, sp_s_fin, sp_e_fin;

            for (int i = 0; i < spans_test.length; i++) {
                sp_start = spannable.getSpanStart(spans_test[i]);
                sp_end = spannable.getSpanEnd(spans_test[i]);
                flags = spannable.getSpanFlags(spans_test[i]);
                sp_s_fin = sp_start - start_range;
                sp_e_fin = sp_end - start_range;
                if (sp_s_fin < 0) sp_s_fin = 0;
                if (sp_e_fin > builder_test.length() - 1) sp_e_fin = builder_test.length() - 1;
                builder_test.setSpan(spans_test[i], sp_s_fin, sp_e_fin, flags);
            }

            synchronized (this) {
                spannable_page = new WeakReference<Spannable>(builder_test);
            }
```

So, somehow I need track links inside each page.

Comment: Show your code first =)

Comment: Added some code, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution and it was easier than I thought.
The key to make links clickable with PagerAdapter is to put the listener to the page's Fragment class.

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
...
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...


URLSpan[] links = spannable.getSpans(0, spannable.length(), URLSpan.class);
        for (URLSpan span : links) {
            textLinks(spannable, span);
        }
        textView.setText(spannable);
            textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        return view;
    }


private void textLinks(Spannable text, final URLSpan span) {
        int start = text.getSpanStart(span);
        int end = text.getSpanEnd(span);
        int flags = text.getSpanFlags(span);
        ClickableSpan clickable = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("LINK CHECK: " + span.getURL());
            }
        };
        text.setSpan(clickable, start, end, flags);
        text.removeSpan(span);
    }
```